# C# WPF - MainWindow content gets shown in two separate windows instead of one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to have a single `MainWindow` with two columns, a narrow one on the left and a wide one on the right. In the left one should be a menubar and in the right one a grid of `Fields` (which is a custom `ViewModelBase`). However, right now when I launch the program, it gives me two windows, one with the grid and one with the menubar on the left. What am I doing wrong? Where might be the error?

Tha XAML looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="SavageMaci.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="500" Width="700">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="38,0,187,430" Background="White">
            <Menu.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Menu.RenderTransform >
            <MenuItem Header="Level 1" FontFamily="Roboto" Height="32" Width="65"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Level 2" FontFamily="Roboto" Height="32" Width="65"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Level 3" FontFamily="Roboto" Height="32" Width="65"/>
        </Menu>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Size}" Columns="{Binding Size}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The xaml.cs is also basic:

```
namespace SavageMaci
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

There's only one reference to `MainWindow()`, in `App.xaml.cs`, where I instantiate it. Please let me know where else might the error be, I'll update the question with that code, too. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Just for the sake of trying it out, create a separate project and re-create the source files by copying the xaml and cs file contents (do not copy the files themselves, especially not *.g.cs files). Tell me if the problem persists.

Comment: Seems like I'm completely lost. I can't really do what you suggest, since I've got like 8 classes that I'd need to copy/modify for the new dummy project, so I've tried to simple it down and use a `Field` of buttons instead of the custom class. What I'm doing now, you can finde here: https://codeshare.io/5DY1Wa
However, this time I can't even get the grid of buttons to show, even though I'm binding the `Field` of `Button`s to the `Mainwindow`'s `DataContext`...

Comment: I've been there mate, 8 classes is nothing.. I strongly recommend you do what I said so that we can further diagnose the issue. I will have a look at your code in the meanwhile.

Comment: You are missing the ViewModel class.. please provide it and any other classes which exist so that I can properly assess the situation.

Comment: @EyalPerry Added the ViewModel class to the codeshare!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is simple. In your App class, you create a MainWindow instance.

This is unnecessary since App creates its own instance whether you create it or not.

Have a look at the App.xaml file and you will see for yourself.

Comment: Oh thank you! I'll actually need the one one created in the App class, but removing it from the App.xaml helped!